# NSInvocation with value type arguments

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsinvocation

Is it possible to use NSInvocation with value type arguments?

Currently we can do this:

```
[invocation setArgument:&param1 atIndex:2];
```

But we'd like that first parameter to be a value type such as int.

When I look at the variable being passed to the target method in the debbugger it's some junk value like 1.367481856920029E+302 - which seems like it's converting an object's address to an int.

Comment: That's how you do it, where `param1` is an integer or whatever primitive datatype you want. The graphical debugger is sometimes wrong, and note especially if you're using a breakpoint that it won't show the value of an assignment until _after_ the line containing the assignment.

Answer (score 3):

If I get what are you looking for, you just want to pass an int as first parameter?

The solution of this issue should be:

```
NSInteger param1 = 2;
NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:methodSignature];
[invocation setArgument:&param1 atIndex:2];
```

If it's not answering to your question, please add more details/code.